# Laravel search engine only shows some products

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building a search functionality for my eCommerce site, but the results shows only some products, not all. For example, I can find all products named "Abrazadera" but I can not find any other. Thanks for the help.

Route:

```
Route::get('search-product', [
'uses' => 'WelcomeController@searchProduct',
'as' => 'search-product'
```

Controller:

```
public function searchProduct(Request $request){

    // Sets the parameters from the get request to the variables.
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $products = Product::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')->paginate(15);
    $marca = Category::all();
    $marcas = Marcas::all();
    $quicklinks = Quicklinks::all(); 
    return view('tienda.product')->with('products',$products)->with('marca',$marca)->with('marcas',$marcas)->with('quicklinks', $quicklinks);
}
```

HTML

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
{{ $product->name }}
@endforeach
{{ $products->render()}}
        @include('partials.brand')
    @include('partials.footer')
@stop
```

Comment: you are building a search functionality not a search engine

Answer (score 0):

I think product showing according to search and also you have put pagination 15. It will show on next page . And may you have to check with content "%LIKE%" also.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function searchProduct(Request $request){

    // Sets the parameters from the get request to the variables.
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $products = Product::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%');
    $marca = Category::all();
    $marcas = Marcas::all();
    $quicklinks = Quicklinks::all(); 
    return view('tienda.product')->with('products',$products)->with('marca',$marca)->with('marcas',$marcas)->with('quicklinks', $quicklinks);
}
```

Why don't you remove pagination and print the query instead?

This will work.